# Corollary 6.6 in Munkres' TOPOLOGY 2nd ed: Subsets of finite sets are finite? Cardinality of a proper subset is less than that of the set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Here's Corollary 6.6 in *Topology* by James R. Munkres, 2nd edition:

If $B$ is a subset of the finite set $A$, then $B$ is finite. If $B$ is a proper subset of $A$, then the cardinality of $B$ is less than the cardinality of $A$.

How do I supply a proof of this corollary using the preceding material in section 6 of Munkres?

Here are the results that have gone before Corollary 6.6.

Lemma 6.1: Let $n$ be a positive integer. Let $A$ be a set; let $a_0$ be an element of $A$. There exists a bijective correspondence $f$ of the set $A$ with the set $\{1, \ldots, n+1\}$ if and only if there exists a bijective correspondence $g$ of the set $A - \{a_0\}$ with the set $\{1, \ldots, n\}$.

Theorem 6.2: Let $A$ be a set; suppose that there exists a bijection $f \colon A \to \{1, \ldots, n \}$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}_+$. Let $B$ be a proper subset of $A$. Then there exists no bijection $g \colon B \to \{ 1, \ldots, n\}$; but (provided $B \neq \emptyset$) there does exist a bijection $h \colon B \to \{ 1, \ldots, m \}$ for some $m < n$.

Corollary 6.3: If $A$ is finite, there is no bijection of $A$ with a proper subset of itself.

Corollary 6.4: $\mathbb{Z}_+$ is not finite.

Corollary 6.5: The cardinality of a finite set $A$ is uniquely determined by $A$.

Although I've understood the above results quite thoroughly (along with their proofs!), I'm unable to figure out how to come up with a proof of Corollary 6.6 using the preceding material in the section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a direct corollary of Theorem 6.2. If $A$ is finite, what can we conclude ? As $B$ is a subset of $A$, what can we conclude ?

Comment: If $A$ is finite, then either $A$ is the empty set or there exists a bijection of $A$ with the set $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}_+$. If $B = A$, then $B$ is obviously finite. Otherwise, $A$ is non-empty and $B$ is a proper subset of $A$. So there exists no bijection of $B$ with the set $\{1, \ldots, n\}$; moreover, either $B$ is empty or there exists a bijection of $B$ with the set $\{1, \ldots, m\}$ for some $m \in \mathbb{Z}_+$ such that $m < n$. Hence $B$ is finite and the cardinality of $B$ is less than the cardinality of $A$. Am I right?

Comment: Indeed you are.